My Poisson distribution cannot be displayed on the plot
This is a homework of mine to plot the gaussian and poisson distribution for r = 20, mu = 20 and sigma = sqrt(20). But the problem is that the value when computing of the computer is capped somewhere, and the large number like 20^20 cannot be computed, so the graph looks horribly wrong after r >= 8. Here is my code:


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
from scipy.special import factorial

#c)
sigma = np.sqrt(20)
mu1 = 20
b = np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
def fGauss(r):
    return 1/(b * sigma) * np.exp(-(r - mu1)**2 / (2*sigma**2))
def fPoisson2(r):
    return mu1**r * np.exp(-mu1)/factorial(r)

x1 = np.arange(1, 21, 1)
Gauss = [fGauss(r) for r in x1]
Poisson2 = [fPoisson2(r) for r in x1]


plt.bar(x1, Poisson2, color = 'b', alpha = 1, label = 'Poisson-Verteilung')
plt.bar(x1, Gauss, color = 'r', alpha = 0.2, label = 'Gauss-Verteilung')
plt.xlim(-0.1, 20.1)
plt.xticks(x1)
plt.xlabel('r')
plt.ylabel('Wahrscheinlichkeit')
plt.title(r'Poisson- und Gauss-Verteilung für $(\mu = 20; r = 1,2,...,20)$')
plt.show()


I have asked a friend of mine for advice and he said to use np.random.poisson, but I still don't know how to work around it, so I post this here, hoping for help. In attachment is my file.
If anyone has question regarding the task, I will provide as much as I could.
Many thanks

Be careful! It looks like you’re calculating the density for the Gaussian, a continuous distribution, at integer points. Density is not probability. To get probability corresponding to integer r for a continuous distribution, you should evaluate F(r+0.5)-F(r-0.5), where F() is the cumulative distribution function. (To convince yourself that density != probability, consider a right triangle with density function f(x) = 2x for 0 <= x <= 1, and f(x) = 0 elsewhere. At x == 1 you get f(x) == 2, and probabilities can never exceed 1.)

Your intermediate working contains huge (but partially-cancelling) numbers like 20^20 and 20!
You can avoid this by constructing the successive probabilities incrementally, multiplying by mu/i for i = 1, ... r.
Change your Poisson probability function to
def fPoisson2(r):
    answer = np.exp( -mu1 )
    for i in range( 1, r + 1 ): answer *= mu1 / i
    return answer

and you will be OK.
Note that the normal distribution will be a close approximation to Poisson for mu this large.

You’re right about the Gaussian being a close approximation to Poisson with that parameterization, but the plots won’t show this without the continuity correction in conjunction with the CDF described in my comment below the question.

Fair point, but I was interested in getting the Poisson distribution to return a value at all, rather than struggling with large numbers.
